# Can't secure supply of 32mhz Automotive grade oscillator - why is this?

Tags: components, bom, sourcing

This is my first automotive PCB. I designed in a high temp crystal from Digikey. Stock then went to 0 with big lead times, and then my alternate went EOL. I then spun the board with a TCXO. All three parts I had picked went to 0 stock. I then sourced from a manufacturer, and then this went EOL.

Isn't a high temp 32Mhz oscillator a common thing in automotive just like a 32Mhz oscillator is in a consumer product? It sounds like it isn't. I never had trouble in consumer. Can someone tell me what I don't know about sourcing this part and not having to re-source it every 3 months?

It is hard without a mentor, or experience in automotive, to find who knows what I need to know. So far the buyers don't know the answer, and the manufacturers are not responding (if they know).

Comment: Crystals don’t really like high vibration environments. Have you looked at clock generators from the likes of Silicon Labs, Maxim, Cypress?

Comment: I just searched on Digikey and there was plenty of 32MHz oscillators offering high temperature ratings, and even some offering automotive qualifications.  Some examples are ASEAIG-32.000MHZ-C-S-T   MC2016K32.0000C16ESH    ECS-3225MVQ-320-BP-TR   SIT8924BE-72-33N-32.000000E.

Comment: I need 2x1.6mm package because the board is tiny. Maybe that is it.

Comment: I can't spin unless it is critical, so the package and pins have to match. The IC has internal adjustable caps but there is a specific ppm, and Cl.

Comment: This is totally a side point and normally I wouldn't even mention it, but because of your situation I figure it is worth mentioning that you should really capitalize it MHz. (Not mhz or Mhz).  Maybe if you are entering the description in some part database where all caps are used you could do MHZ. But whenever possible, the capitalization should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't a high temp 32Mhz oscillator a common thing in automotive just
> like a 32Mhz oscillator is in a consumer product?

In general there are many more parts meeting commercial specs than there are with an automotive qualification.  This is not unique to oscillators specifically.

When selecting a part you should check where the product is in its life cycle.  You use tools like "part intelligence" to find out this information.  This will allow you to make an estimate of how long the part will be available.

Comment: I wanted to see if there was some industry specific knowledge, like no one uses micros in high temp if they can, they do X. Or manufacturers aren't serious about these parts, etc. Sounds like normal supply issues.

Comment: Most of the work I do is for automotive environments and we routinely use processors, micro-controllers, and FPGAs.  As well as popular standards like USB, Ethernet, etc.